# How to set mix-blend-mode: linear burn from photoshop to css?

Tags: css, photoshop, mix-blend-mode

[image: Photoshop mode Linear Burn]

I have tried many ways to set it up but it's not the same as the design. Have you ever encountered this situation?

```css
`span::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(`images.png`);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 404px auto;
    background-position: top 43px left -7px;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}`
```